# Realtek 8186 - Any difference using G only?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Is there any difference in output power/quality if I set the router as G only, since I have only G equipment? It's sort of stupid question since if there is only G obviously I should set as G only, but the fact is that I remember running some tests and apparently if it's in B/G mode it would work faster in G.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [National Instrument's white paper](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7131/en/)  `g` will be provide you more data rate up to ~170 -200 feet (~50- 60 meter) comparing to `b`, then you will get the same performance for the data rate point of view

[image]

Comment: I believe you didn't understand the question, I'm not comparing setting router to B or G, I'm asking in configuring it in G only mode or G/B mode.